# Sum of even numbers in Python

Tags: python

At uni we had the following problem: Create a function that is expecting an argument (an integer n) and that is returning the sum of all positive, even numbers between 1 and n. I tried the following solution:

```
def even_sum(number):
    count = 0
    sum = 0
    while count <= number:
        if count%2 == 0:
            sum = sum + count
            count = count + 1  
    return sum
```

But Python would just keep on loading. Why doesn't it work? In the end, I found this alternative solution that did work

```
def even_sum(number):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0,number+1,2):
        sum = sum + i
    return sum
```

But I still kept on wondering what the problem was with the first solution.

Comment: `count` should increment each time through the loop.  `count = count + 1` shouldn't be underneath the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the indentation in the `count = count + 1` line. You need to execute that instruction on the while, not inside the `if` condition, because that will lead to an infinite loop. To achieve that, place the line at the same indentation level as the `while` loop:

```
def even_sum(number):
  count = 0
  sum = 0
  while count <= number:
    if count%2 == 0:
      sum = sum + count
    count = count + 1  
  return sum
```

To better understand what is going on here, take a look at the value of count with the old solution:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

As you can see, `count` has a fixed value on each execution of the while loop because it only increments if it finds an even number, but when it falls on odd numbers, it never changes and causes that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your `count = count + 1` is indented underneath the `if`.  So for odd numbers, you never increment the count and you end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could sum a generator expression instead if you want a faster solution:

```
def even_sum(number):
    return sum(i for i in range(0, number+1, 2))
```

Edit:
Actually you can just sum `range` itself which is even faster:

```
def even_sum(number):
    return sum(range(0, number+1, 2))
```

Comment: Except... the OP wasn't looking for a rewrite of their solution. They just wanted help figuring out what was wrong (which was quickly deduced and posted). And what you wrote is more advanced than a loop-based solution - I suspect they're just learning at this point, so...

Comment: aren't we all...

Comment: @DavidMakogon also incorrect indentation apparently counts as a typo and the question shouldn't be answered anyway https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72028813/what-is-difference-between-two-codes-written-here-the-output-of-both-codes-are/72028879#72028879

Comment: A comment would indeed have sufficed, to let the OP know what the issue was. And I already voted to close this question as typo/not reproducible.